# How to use "--experimental-repl-await" command-line option with Node.js REPL module?

Tags: node.js

In Node.js I use REPL module like this:

```js
const repl = require('repl')

repl.start(':> ')
```

Is it possible to pass `--experimental-repl-await' option to it?

Comment: I'm not sure how to enable that option programmatically, but what version of node are you using? At least in 16.6, `await` is enabled at the REPL by default.

Comment: WoW, I did't know that! Thank you very much.